# Autowired is not working but manually creating an object works

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I was trying to autowire an object in my class. No errors or exceptions were thrown, but if I call a method of that, it just won't work. What did I miss here?

This is how I autowire the object:

```
    @Autowired
    RetryOnException retry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CimsMigrationSftp100Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        while(retry.shouldRetry()) {
           // More codes here and below
        }
```

If I use `RetryOnException retry = new RetryOnException();`, it will work, and I can jump into the while loop. What is the difference between dependency injection and creating an object manually?

Below is `RetryOnException()`:

```
import static package.PAUSE_MS;
import static package.POST_MAX_RETRIES;
@Component
public class RetryOnException {

    private int numberOfRetries;
    private int numberOfTriesLeft;
    private long timeToWait;

    public RetryOnException() {
        this(POST_MAX_RETRIES, PAUSE_MS);
    }

    public RetryOnException(int numberOfRetries,
            long timeToWait) {
        this.numberOfRetries = numberOfRetries;
        numberOfTriesLeft = numberOfRetries;
        this.timeToWait = timeToWait;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if there are tries left
     */
    public boolean shouldRetry() {
        return numberOfTriesLeft > 0;
    }

    public void errorOccured() throws Exception {
        numberOfTriesLeft--;
        if (!shouldRetry()) {
            throw new Exception("Retry Failed: Total " + numberOfRetries
                    + " attempts made at interval " + getTimeToWait()
                    + "ms");
        }
        waitUntilNextTry();
    }

    public long getTimeToWait() {
        return timeToWait;
    }

    private void waitUntilNextTry() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(getTimeToWait());
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what does "if I call a method of that, it just won't work" mean? What exception do you get?

Comment: Please post the full class, not just a snippet.

Comment: is `RetryOnException ` on a scannable path?

Comment: @f1sh By 'it just won't work', I mean I could not go into the `while` loop. If I create the object manually, I can go into the `while` loop at the beginning of the `main`.

Comment: @lakshman I tried to put `@ComponentScan` at `RetryOnException`, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add **@Autowired** on the constructor of your **RetryOnException** class.
You have multiple constructors and spring does not know which one to use to create your object.

Comment: Seems like this is the problem! If I put `@Autowired` on the first constructor, and I replace `POST_MAX_RETRIES' and `PAUSE_MS` with an integer and a long, it works normally. Now the issue is, those 2 static variables are not initialized yet before object injection happens?

Comment: Static variables are initialised when classloader loads classes, so before dependency injection and before object is created

Answer (score 0):

There should also be component scan annotation so that spring knows which packages to scan to find components.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.your.package.withcomponents")
public class AppConfig{}
```

References:

1. [Official Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)
2. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)